# How to add extentions automatically in Visual Studo 2017?

Tags: visual-studio

I have uwp project  in repository which use wrapper(extension) "SQLite for uwp". When I clone my project from new pc i always need download and install extension manually("tool -> extensions and updates -> uwp->..).
How to do it automatically? Something like nuget packages..

Comment: @nopassport1: The questions is apparently for Visual Studio (VS 2017, judging from the mentioned menu structure), not for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @PeterMacej my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way how to force the installation of a VS extension. It's a good thing because I would be quite upset if a VS project installed an extension on my machine.

Isn't the [SQLite.UWP.Native](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.UWP.Native/) nuget package what you need?